# mongoose findByIdAndUpdate, not updating document , seems to be receiving correct parameters

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Method in model:

```
DistillerSchema.methods.update = function(o, u, cb){
  this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(o, u, cb);
};
```

controller:

```
exports.update = function(req, res){
  console.log('Bodddyyy!!!!!!!', req.body);
  console.log('params', req.params);
  Distiller.update(req.body._id, req.body, function(err, distiller){
    console.log('update!!!!', distiller);
    res.send({distiller:distiller});
  });
};
```

console.log:

```
Bodddyyy!!!!!!! { _id: '573592584435639d18242d3c',
  name: 'chewbacca333333',
  email: 'chewbacca@chew.com',
  photo: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/whiskey-upload/distillers/9ec98f42-7d43-4be9-a372-2a0e90cd4f30',
  __v: 0,
  social:
   { facebook: 'https://www.facebook.com',
     twitter: 'https://www.facebook.com',
     instagram: 'https://www.facebook.com' },
  whiskeys: [],
  location: [],
  timestamp: '2016-05-13T08:37:44.257Z' }
params { id: '573592584435639d18242d3c' }
update!!!! { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm passing in all the correct data from the client side, and according to the mongoose documentation, I feel i'm passing the correct parameters.

It keeps returning: { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Maybe something with how I have the method in the model?

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to try and define your own `update` method on the schema. Try giving that method another name.

Comment: I just thought the same thing. Seems like there would be a conflict.

Comment: additionally, it should have been a static method. I need to look into the concepts of static / methods more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as was mentioned via comment, the names seem to be conflicting & you need to swap method type.

Comment: Thanks. I was waiting to see if @johnnyHK would submit an answer. But, that did resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should call: `req.body._id` or `req.params.id`.

But you're calling `req.body.id`

Comment: Good catch. I forgot to change it back. I initially had it at req.body._id, then had tried to change it to req.params.id while debugging, which resulted in a typo. I've made sure it's pointing to the correct id value, but still getting the same error.